# Use variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem how to keep value of `portsElement[i].Id` during selection change in `ComboBox`. I've tried to make global variable, but during selection change in `ComboBox` it's showing me `undefined`.

My first try was to make variable, but that variable kept only the last value in all ComboBox-es.

```
for (var i = 0; i < portsElement.length; i++) {

     window['portId' + i] = portsElement[i].Id;  //this is the variable I would like to keep for each loop                                                                                                                          
     var cBox = new App.Components.ComboBox({                                                                                                                         
          listeners: {
             select: function (combo, record, index) {
                UpdateElementRefDetails({ Id: window['portId' + i] }, function () {
                    me.el.unmask();
                });
            }
        }
    });                                                            
}
```

Comment: You can use `let i` in pretty much anything outside of IE. You can use Babel to transpile your code and then you'd be able to use `let` in every browser.

Comment: Works like a charm. Please post as answer if it is possible.

Comment: No need for another answer. The [(in)famous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1451009) already has many good canonical answers - I've linked to the duplicate. You'll find it at the top of the question.